# Is there Qt API which differentiates between Removable Drives and a SD Card?

Tags: qt, qt4, sd-card, usb-drive

I am working on a Qt application where I have a QTreewidget which displays the removable drives and local drives. I have set an icon each for local drives and a separate icon for removable drive.

I have 2 removable drives... One is a USB and other is a SDCard. Both are appearing as Removable drives in my treewidget with the same icon. I want to set 2 different icons. An SD icon for SD card and Removable drive icon for USB drive.

Is their a Qt API which can let me know whether the connected device is a USB drive(Removable Drive) or a SDCard(Using a sd card reader)?? Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using `QFileSystemModel` for your view. It uses `QFileSystemIconProvider` to generate icons. The implementation of this class is very OS-dependent. Most likely it just requests icons from underlying system and doesn't even know the real types of drives. Anyway, it doesn't expose any methods that could be useful for this.

So, the answer is no. There is no API to obtain this information. You need to use some platform-specific functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is their any other API which can give me the list of drives and the type of drives? I tried `QFSFileEngine`and it gives me list of all drives.... But doesnt help me to figure out which is a removable drive.